# Can we set javascript to load asynchronously with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Suppose I have this HTML Content:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="myscript1.js"></script>
<script src="myscript2.js"></script>
<script src="myscript3.js"></script>
<script src="myscript4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--- CONTENT --->
...
.
.
.
.
.
<!--- CONTENT --->
</body>
</html>
```

Can I do like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="myscript1.js"></script>
<script src="myscript2.js"></script>
<script src="myscript3.js"></script>
<script src="myscript4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("script").attr("async","async");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--- CONTENT --->
...
.
.
.
.
.
<!--- CONTENT --->
</body>
</html>
```

Is that valid? And would that actually asynchronously load the javascript or not? :)

Thanks for your time...!

.....................................................................................

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1):

That wouldn't work.

1. The script element is blocking, so the script to add the `asynchronous` attribute wouldn't run until all the previous scripts had run, but which time it would be too late.
2. You've wrapped the script that adds the attribute in a DOM Ready handler, so even if 1 wasn't true, it still wouldn't work.
3. The attribute is [`async`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#dom-script-async), not `asynchronous`

You need to add the (correct) attribute before the script element is added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. As you are printing the script tags BEFORE your jquery code, the browser will load those scripts file before running your code.

Comment: Okay, say I added that before every script. Would that work then?

Comment: No i won't work either, as when you are looking for the script tags with jQuery, the scripts are not printed yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getScript()` to load scripts asynchronously

```
$.getScript("/path/to/script.js",function(){
  // loaded
});
```

`----->`  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/